# Describing the type of family a person belongs to

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, concision

Okay, trying to come at this from a different angle...

I need a more concise way to say "Families for which you are a child and therefore show your siblings and parents" – something that would be suitable for a title of a table/listing. Additionally, I need a more concise way to say "Families for which you are a parent and therefore show your spouses and direct descendants." Again, something that would be suitable for a title of a table/listing.

Ideally I'm looking for a single word to precede "Families" for both titles, but 3 or 4 words at most would be okay as well. I just don't want to put a full sentence as a title.

---

Originally Asked:

I'm listing two types of families. One where the person is a parent and the other where the person is a child. The title for the section listing families where the person is a parent I'm using "Parental Families". I'm not sure what to use for the title for the section listing families where the person is a child. I really don't thing *Childal* is a word :)

Per Bradd Szonye's comment:

> Are there specific terms for your immediate family including your children, versus your immediate family including your parents?

If there are no specific terms, what the best way to title the two grouping on a report?

Example 1 (Parental Families):

```
*Person* & Spouse 1 (divorces)
    Child 1
    Child 2
    Child 3

*Person* & Spouse 2 (so there are 2 families)
    Child 4
    Child 5
```

Example 2 (??? Families):

```
Spouse 1 & Spouse 2 (first marriage)
    *Person*  (biological)
    Child 2   (biological)
    Child 3   (biological)

Spouse 1 & Spouse 3 (2nd marriage)
    *Person*  (adopted or step)
    Child 2   (adopted or step)
    Child 3   (adopted or step)
    Child 4   (biological)
```

Comment: Children? I'm having difficulty understanding "families where the *person* is a child". Could you be clearer or give examples?

Comment: I worked abroad for a number of years and people kept asking if I had brought my family with me.  As a single person at that stage, I understood my family to mean my parents and siblings, while they had intended it to mean my spouse and children.

Comment: @Henry That makes sense, but let's see what the OP means?

Comment: @Justin808 Do you mean from the *perspective* of a spouse and from the perspective of a *child*. *Spousal* is [defined](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spousal?q=spousal) as "relating to marriage or to a husband or wife: *the spousal benefits of married couples*". "Spousal family" sounds odd. I would struggle to guess what it means, but would assume it means a *married* family with *mother & father* (i.e. a family where there is a *spouse*), as distinct from a *one-parent family* and also excluding two-parent families where the parents are not married. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think Henry's got it. As a child, your immediate family refers to your parents and siblings, but as an adult, it refers to your spouse and children. I'm not sure there's any term in English that distinguishes between the two though. The meaning of the word *family* is defined by the context.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I've added examples

Comment: @Justin808 I'm still not sure what you're asking for. Both of your examples seem to involve re-marriage; is that important? Neither of your examples include single parents; is that important? What exactly are the distinctions and nuances you're trying to convey? Part of the difficulty is that these aren't two types of _families_ at all; they all have two married parents and some children. The part that differs is the _relationship_ between the subject and the family, and I have a hard time imagining a term for that of the form _X family._

Comment: @BraddSzonye - in the first 2 families the Person is a parent. in the last 2 families the person is a child. The number of parents in the family doesn't matter. The difference is in the position the person holds in the family.

Comment: If what you care about is the parent vs child relationship, you should probably remove all references to spouses in your question, as single parents are not spouses, and mentioning the spousal relationship only confuses things.

Comment: For example, consider asking like this: “Are there specific terms for your immediate family including your children, versus your immediate family including your parents?”

Comment: @BraddSzonye - Rewrote to remove spouse... Sorry, I'm trying to make it as clear as I can based on whats in my head :).

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I deleted the 2nd question.

Comment: @justin808 I'm sure someone out there can help you. Fingers crossed! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All four of your examples describe an **immediate** or **nuclear family.** In English, we naturally use *immediate family* to denote your spouse(s) and child(ren) if you are a parent, your sibling(s) and parent(s) if you are a child. To distinguish the two cases, the most natural terminology would be **a child's immediate family** and **a parent's immediate family.**

Comment: What about when you have 3 tiers: grandparents, their children, & grandchildren? The *immediate* family of the middle generation includes both *their* parents & *their* children. This also illustrates why OP's question is nonsensical.

Comment: Unless the extended family all lives together, you'd then use _nuclear family_ to describe just the two generations living in the same household. The original question had some issues, but I don't think it's nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

The added examples in the question seem to confirm what I suggested in an earlier comment.

*All* of the family groupings shown in the examples consist of:

- two parents (or step-parent), and
- one or more children (and/or step-children)

**You cannot refer to these as different *types* of families**: they are *all* the same *type* of family, *consisting of the same constituents*, namely parents and children.

Specifically, you cannot properly call your first examples "Parental families", because *all* of the family groups in *both examples* include parents. If you refer to one group as "Parental families", then the clear implication is that the other family groups do not include parents.

What you appear to be asking about is viewing the *same* family group from different perspectives.

1. In your **Example 1** families, you are viewing the group *from the perspective of a parent*, whereas
2. in your **Example 2** families, you are viewing the group *from the perspective of a child*.

The *members* (or constituents) of the family group remain the same. It is still the same *type* of family, but just viewed from a different perspective.

A hill is still a hill, whether you view it from the top looking down or from the bottom looking up.

The only suggestions I can offer to distinguish your two examples are:

1. Parental perspective [of family]
2. Child perspective [of family]

Comment: There is also [consanguineous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consanguineous_family) family. So "non-consanguineous family" might also be appropriate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA (New word for me!) I don't think that's what OP is asking about, since *both* of his 'types' seem to include the possibility of step children/parents and/or adoption. One of his comments specifically says "The difference is in the *position* the person holds in the family", which is what I've tried to address.

Comment: Neither step-children nor adopted ones are consanguineous relations. (I knew the Italian expression and translated it= http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consanguineous)

Comment: @TrevorD - They are not the same family group, They are four different families. Example 1 the position in the family the person holds is a Parent. In example 2 the position in the family the person holds is Child. Maybe I'm looking for a term that just doesn't exist. I'll try one more edit.

Comment: @Justin808 four different family groups? 1) parent 2) biological child 3)step-parent 4)step-child. But as Trevor pointed out, we're still talking about parents and their "biological" and "non-biological" descendants, so two different perspectives.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Just two groups 1) person is a parent, 2) person is a child. It doesn't matter the type of child

Comment: @Justin808 I think TrevorD's point is that all four of these families are the same type: a nuclear family. Viewing the families from the point of view of a parent or a child doesn't really change the nature of the family, just the relationship.

Comment: @Justin808 Bradd is correct. The families are still a standard family consisting of parent and children. Take the *first* family group from your 2 examples. It consists of Spouses 1 & 2 (S1 & S2) and Children 1-3 (C1, C2, C3). In your Ex.1, you are looking at it from the perspective of S2. In Ex.2, you are looking at it from the perspective of C1. But *in both cases*, it is the *same people* S1,S2,C1,C2,C3 - they are the *same people* in the *same family* so it cannot simultaneously be 2 *different* family 'types'

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can either have parents and their children, or children and their parents or siblings, but there's no ready way to conceive of them as different forms of family, beyond the notion of a single parent family.